# TRUNC(CASE from Oracle to T-Sql Server

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Hey ther I been trying to conver a database from Oracle to Sql Server format, ther eis a line I'm having issues with, I will appreciate some help in here.

Oracle line:

```
TRUNC(CASE WHEN (b.rsn IS NOT NULL OR A.zeroreport = 1) AND b.datereceived IS NULL THEN A.datereceived ELSE b.datereceived END),
```

I have been trying to convert it to SQl Server and so far I got:

> CASE WHEN (b.rsn IS NOT NULL OR A.zeroreport = 1) AND b.datereceived
>   IS NULL THEN A.datereceived ELSE b.datereceived END

,
 but not sure if that is the right way. I just removed the trun( not sure if I need it

Answer (score 0):

You are using `trunc` to get the date portion.  You can do this in SQL Server by casting to a date.  I think I would go for:

```
(CASE WHEN (b.rsn IS NOT NULL OR A.zeroreport = 1) AND b.datereceived IS NULL
      THEN CAST(A.datereceived as DATE)
      ELSE CAST(b.datereceived as DATE)
 END),
```

Or, if you prefer `CONVERT()`, it is easier to read with `CASE` as the first argument:

```
CONVERT(DATE,
        (CASE WHEN (b.rsn IS NOT NULL OR A.zeroreport = 1) AND b.datereceived IS NULL
              THEN A.datereceived
              ELSE b.datereceived
         END),
        )
```